# Outlook: When exporting contacts, how can I force the email type to be 'SMTP' instead of 'Exchange'?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, export, contacts, activex

With Outlook, I can [export my contacts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx) to a file; and I typically like to export my contacts to an Excel file.

Unfortunately, if I've added contacts from my corporate network, Outlook will, by default, export these contacts' email addresses **with an 'EX' EmailType**.

My Question:

- How can I force Outlook to export my contacts' email addresses as their SMTP equivalents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Outlook contact were synced to Outlook by another application like Lync or other Microsoft Exchange enabled application, the email addresses that get exported from Outlook will be in the EX format. You will have to copy the contacts to a unique contact card and then export again.

Test this using a single contact before copy all cards though to ensure there is no other blocker.